# How to add multiline header & footer with a JTable in java?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I need to print & save .ps file which contains multiline header  & footer  in between a `JTable` from my java application.

I have used `getPrintable()` and wrapped it with Custom code but i was getting the header space just adjusted not the lines.

All lines in the header getting printed in the same line.

Is there any way to print with mulitline header in java.

Comment: Why not use a better tool for the task, such as a printable form-generating library?

Comment: Can you name some of those libraries @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Such as JasperReports.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 !!